# Hide/Show <div> according to URL in Prototype

Tags: javascript, url, prototypejs, show-hide, scriptaculous

I am trying to use the prototype framework to hide a '< div >' based on a particular URL. I don't have access to server side - so I have no choice but to do this using prototype [restriction of platform using prototype].

Wondering if someone could tell me how to do this in prototype framework ?

i.e. I tried to do this but doesn't work

> Event.observe(window, 'load',
>   function() {
>
> var url = document.location.href;
>
> if (url.indexOf('registered') >=
>   0) {
>   $$('#side-menu-right').hide(); }
>
> if (url.indexOf('login') >= 0)
>   {   $$('#side-menu-left').hide();
>   }
>
> });

Love some help ?

P.S - Never used Prototype [jQuery man right here yo!]

Comment: With Prototype you can use document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {... }); as an "onready" function.

Comment: hey thanks a lot :) my prob is that some scripts on the platform i am using are loading first and the system automatically shoves my script down the bottom. page elements load and then my menu is hidden [delayed]. any clever ideas to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a test case on [**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/onoce/edit) which complains:

```
Exception thrown: $$("#hello").hide is not a function
Caused by line (23/21): $$('#hello').hide();
```

(using latest version of Prototype)

When using:

```
$('hello').style.display = "none";
```

it works correctly, see [**example**](http://jsbin.com/onoce/2/edit).

**EDIT:** I adjusted the **[example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/onoce/5/edit)** to conditionally add a class name to the `body` before the involved element is reached. Using

```
.registered-user #hello { display: none; }
```

The element doesn't show up at all. It's not the most neat solution, as you have to throw some `script` in the middle of your document, but it works. If someone knows a better solution, please tell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .registered-user #hello { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('registered')>=0)
      $$('body')[0].addClassName('registered-user');
  </script>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response :) any ideas how to fix ? i am not even sure if this is correct in prototype

Comment: thanks! one thing - this works now )) but when the page loads - it appears then the javascript kicks in.

any way to use something like "document(ready)" or even when its not ready ? [not sure of such a function in prototype]

Comment: @Thomas: you mean the flickering (element is shown and immediately hidden)? You can only prevent that when you change some CSS rules *before* the mentioned element is drawn. I'll make an example.

Comment: thanks so much :) yeah basically the elements appears - "then" it is hidden

Comment: legend - thanks a lot for the great answer. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$$('#side-menu-right').hide();
```

to

```
$('side-menu-right').hide();
```

Hope this helps.

**Reason** 

1) As you can see, JQuery uses CSS notation while Prototype is straight Javascript (so no `#side-menu-right` for `div` with an ID).

2) `Struts` and `Prototype` uses `$` and **not** `$$`.

Comment: hey thanks - i just keep getting $$('side-menu-right').hide(); is not a function ? i really not sure ? [ps - using both # and without]